# How to send output parameters from a job to another job that has reusable workflow from the same workspace

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I'm working on a reusable GitHub Action workflow. I have a problem when I send the variables data to the reusable workflow, the variables are null when the reusable workflow is executed, here is an example:

```yaml
name: Create Package
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
   inputs:
    UploadType:
      description: 'Upload Type'
      default: 'Beta'
      type: choice
      options:
       - Beta
       - Patch
       - Release
jobs:
  access-variables:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      USERNAME_TEST: ${{ steps.variables.outputs.USERNAME_TEST}}
    steps:
      - name: Send Outputs
        id: variables
        run: |
          USERNAME_TEST='OutputToSend'
          echo "USERNAME_TEST=$USERNAME_TEST" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  test_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: access-variables
    steps:
      - name: Print Data Test
        run: |
          echo "UploadType: ${{ github.event.inputs.UploadType }}"
          echo "USERNAME_TEST: ${{ needs.access-variables.outputs.USERNAME_TEST }}"

  create-package:
    needs: access-variables
    uses: WorkspaceName-git/CIHub/.github/workflows/CreatePackage.yml@master
    with:
      UploadType: ${{ github.event.inputs.UploadType }}
      USERNAME_TEST: ${{ needs.access-variables.outputs.USERNAME_TEST }}
```

The reusable workflow contains:

```yaml
name: Create Package

on:
   workflow_call:
    # Inputs the workflow accepts.
    inputs:
      UploadType:
        description: 'Upload Type'
        required: true
        type: string
      USERNAME_TEST:
        description: 'USERNAME_TEST'
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout Repository'
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: 'Inputs Details'
      run: |
         echo "Upload Type: ${{ github.event.inputs.UploadType }}"
         echo ------------------------------
         echo "USERNAME_TEST: ${{ github.event.inputs.USERNAME_TEST }}"
```

Here's the result:

- in the job `test_job`, the values are printed correctly for `UploadType` and `USERNAME_TEST`.
- in the job `create-package`, I send the values to the reusable workflow (`CreatePackage.yml`), in the reusable workflow the `UploadType` is printed and used correctly, but the `USERNAME_TEST` **is empty and does not have any value**.

Is it possible that when I use a reusable workflow I can't get the variable from GitHub output context?

Answer (score 1):

According to [`workflow_call`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_call) event:

> When a workflow is triggered with the `workflow_call` event, the event payload in the called workflow is the same event payload from the calling workflow.

This implies that `github.event` won't be updated for the called workflow and that's what you're observing.

And, according to the [`inputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context) context:

> The `inputs` context contains input properties passed to an action, to a reusable workflow, or to a manually triggered workflow.

So, using `inputs.USERNAME_TEST` instead of `github.event.inputs.USERNAME_TEST` should work.

---

I've verified this with these test workflows (similar to your scenario):

`.github/workflows/ci-reusable-workflow-inputs-caller.yml`

````yaml
name: reusable_workflow_inputs_caller

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input:
        description: 'input'
        type: string
        required: true
        default: 'INPUT'

jobs:
  set:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output: ${{ steps.set.outputs.output }}
    steps:
    - name: Set
      id: set
      run: |
        output='OUTPUT'
        echo "output=$output" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  get:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: set
    steps:
    - name: Get
      run: |
        {
          echo '```yml'
          echo 'inputs.input: ${{ inputs.input }}'
          echo 'steps.set.outputs.output: ${{ needs.set.outputs.output }}'
          echo '```'
        } | tee -a "$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY"

  callee:
    name: callee
    needs: [set, get]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci-reusable-workflow-inputs-callee.yml
    with:
      input: ${{ inputs.input }}
      output: ${{ needs.set.outputs.output }}
````

`.github/workflows/ci-reusable-workflow-inputs-callee.yml`

````yaml
name: reusable_workflow_inputs_callee

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      input:
        description: 'input'
        required: true
        type: string
      output:
        description: 'output'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check
      run: |
        {
          echo '```yml'
          echo 'inputs.input: ${{ inputs.input }}'
          echo 'inputs.output: ${{ inputs.output }}'
          echo 'github.event.inputs.input: ${{ github.event.inputs.input }}'
          echo 'github.event.inputs.output: ${{ github.event.inputs.output }}'
          echo '```'
        } | tee -a "$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY"
````

Output:

[image: output]

Observe that `github.event.inputs.output` is empty in the called workflow's step summary.

Comment: it worked for me! thank you @Azeem, it make sense for me now, thank you also for the explanations